# Can't save a file in a Documents directory in macOS

Tags: swift, swift3

I created a function to save a `data.txt` file in `~/Documents` directory.

But it doesn't save a file at all.

```
func SaveFile(){
        print("save file")
        let file_name = "data.txt"
        let text = "12345"
        let fm = FileManager.default
            do {
                let docsurl = try! fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
                let fileURL = docsurl.appendingPathComponent(file_name)
                try text.write( to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8 )
            } catch {
               print("error: \(error)")
            }

    }
```

In the output area there is only text `save file`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code is supposed to work. Is the app sandboxed? If yes, be aware that the file is saved in the container.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the sandbox is on by default. I'll check as an accepted answer if you write your comment as an answer.